# Is there a way to change between browser tabs programatically?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tabs

I'm trying to implement the following feature:

1. You are on website A
2. You open a link with `target=_blank` that goes to website B, in a new tab of course
3. On website B, there is a link that will make refocus on tab for website A.

Please note that I'm developing both websites and both are in Angular. Is there a way to implement this?

The purpose is not to lose the website state, otherwise I could just redirect the user by the website urls, however I'd lose state.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you could, you really probably shouldn't. But, if state is all your worried about, what about storing it in localstorage or a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform such action in JS, it would be a nightmare for everyone.

But... link on website B can just be a `window.close()`... Previous one will be re-focused.

Is it good for you?

Comment: It would work only if the user didn't open another one in the meanwhile...We can't guarantee that the previous one is actually the one where website A is open. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the browser tab that the user is looking at, due to security concerns. Instead, consider redirecting the user and persisting the data in some appropriate way (e.g. a service)

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Actually that's the proper approach, let's see if it's worth it to pursue this or just drop the feature.